# Creating a text file from an online dictionary's source code - TypeError: POST data should be bytes or an iterable of bytes. It cannot be of type str

Tags: python, ubuntu, dictionary, beautifulsoup, pycharm

I'm new to the forum, but I've searched everywhere and can't find anyone trying to create a similar program as mine.

Basically, I want to (eventually) take an input word in French, tack it on to the end of "http:/www.wordreference.com/fren/" (wordreference is an online dictionary), and somehow, probably using the site's source code, take the word's translation and insert it into a text document along with the original entry.

For example, the input "heureux" would yield "happy", the first translation listed on the site there. However, I'm not that far into the process yet; I'm stuck on something simple — accessing the source code. I found that for every dictionary entry, wordreference starts out the source code with "`td class='ToWrd'`" . So, my logic was to find the first instance of that in the source code and add it to a text document.

Unfortunately, using the method BeautifulSoup in conjunction with the urlopen capacity, I didn't manage to get past the first step.

Here is my code:

```
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = urlopen("http://www.wordreference.com/fren/lame","lxml" )
content = url.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
links = soup.findAll("td class='ToWrd'")
```

I'm just getting: "`TypeError: POST data should be bytes or an iterable of bytes. It cannot be of type str.`"
This task is complicated, but what advice would you give me? I would really appreciate it. I am new to python but I've put in a lot of effort to solving this problem. Thank you very much.

P.S. I am using Python 3.5 via PyCharm on Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

As recommended in `urllib`'s documentation, you should rather use the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library for HTTP.

See also the syntax for using `findall`. You will have to narrow your results a bit more if you want to keep only the first translation.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "http://www.wordreference.com/fren/lame"
content = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html5lib")
links = soup.findAll("td", { "class" : "ToWrd"})
print(links)

# [<td class="ToWrd">Anglais</td>, <td class="ToWrd">blade <em class="tooltip POS2">n<span><i>noun</i>: Refers to person, place, thing, quality, etc. </span></em></td>, ... ]
```